# shift register using dff verilog

Tags: verilog, flip-flop, shift-register

I want to create a shift register using d-flip-flop as basic structural element.
code:

dff:

```
  module dff(d,q,clk,rst);

  input d,clk,rst;
  output reg q;

  always @(posedge clk)
     begin:dff_block
        if(rst==1'b1)
          q=1'b0;
        else
          q=d;
     end
  endmodule
```

shift register:

```
  module shift_register(s1,d,clk,s0,q);
  parameter n=3;

  input  s1,clk;
  input [n:0] d;

  output s0;
  output [n:0] q;

  genvar i;

  assign d[3]=s1;


  generate
  for(i=0; i<=n; i=i+1)
     dff U1(.d(d[i]),.q(q[i]),.clk(clk));
  endgenerate

  assign q[3]=d[2];
  assign q[2]=d[1];
  assign q[1]=d[0];
  assign q[0]=s0;



  endmodule
```

test bench:

```
  module tb();

  parameter n=3;
  reg [n:0] d;
  reg s1,clk;

  wire [n:0] q;
  wire s0;


  shift_register UUT(.s1(s1),.d(d),.clk(clk),.q(q),.s0(s0));

  initial begin

  d=4'b0000;
  clk=0;
  end


always
begin:clok
#10 clk=~clk; s1=1;

end
endmodule
```

I think test bench has the problem.I have tried to give s1 values for every #10 while clk=1 but again does not work.

This code does not give me waveforms for q and s0.I cant find whats wrong.Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: i used <=  but it did not change something...what do you mean about drive s0?

Comment: s0 is the 1 bit serial output of the register so i assigned it to q[0] wich takes values last.(msb->lsb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have several problems with the code.

1. `q` is an output reg of dff; `q[i]` is passed as `q` to dff. `q[i]` gets also assigned in within the `assign` statement. So, you have multiply driven `wire q[i]` which most likely gets resolved to `x` and never changes. You have your i/o swapped around somewhere.
2. you do not assign anything to `s0`, so it does not change and does not produce any waveform.
3. in this particular case blocking assignments within the flop will not pay any role, but in general they could cause unpredictable simulation results. Use non-blocking.
4. there is not much sense in the `generate` loop there. You can pass full vectors tot he dff and can flop full vectors as well.
5. It looks like you get confused int teh direction of the `assign` statement. It implies direction. `assign q[0] = s0;` means assign value of `s0` to the wire `q[0]`, not vice versa.